# increment progressbar every x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I basically need a jQuery UI progress bar to increment x amount every x seconds. After it reaches 100% it needs to run a function to get some content.

Basically a timer.

**EDIT:** I don't need code to fetch content. I already have that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
var progressBar = $('#progress-bar'),
    width = 0;

progressBar.width(width);

var interval = setInterval(function() {

    width += 10;

    progressBar.css('width', width + '%');

    if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94wKr/).

Comment: Missing a time amount for the setInterval function.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you're using the [jQueryUI progressbar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/):

```
var tick_interval = 1;
var tick_increment = 10;
var tick_function = function() {
    var value = $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value");
    value += tick_increment;
    $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value", value);
    if (value < 100) {
        window.setTimeout(tick_function, tick_interval * 1000);
    } else {
        alert("Done");
    }
};
window.setTimeout(tick_function, tick_interval * 1000);
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/tYhMv/)

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) has a [progress bar widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/). You can set its value inside `setInterval`. Run `clearInterval` when [`complete`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/#event-complete) event is raised.